# Проверка элемента(элемент не должен отображаться)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, test-automation, pytest

Использую связку python3.7 + pytest + seleniumwrapper + chrome.
Необходимо реализовать метод, который позволял бы проверить, что элемент не отображается.
Стандартная конструкция на проверку отображения элемента в seleniumwrapper такова:

```
browser.xpath('//div...')
```

Как реализовать проверку того, что элемент не отображается?

В голове только два варианта:
1. конструкция try except, но это как-то неправильно.
2. unwrap. Но это тоже не по феншую.

Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: `try`/`except` это __правильно__, по крайней мере в python стиль [EAFP](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html) предпочтителен. Это и в официальной документации [упоминается](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге решил свою проблему вот таким способом:

```
def element_visible_status(self, xpath):
    """ Метод проверяет видимость элемента на странице.

    :param xpath: xpath элемента для проверки.
    :return: Возвращает статус видимости элемента.
    True - элемент отображается. False - элемент не отображается.
    """
    self.driver.silent = True
    element = self.driver.xpath(xpath, timeout=1)
    self.driver.silent = False
    if element is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Про метод silent можно подробнее прочитать вот тут
https://pypi.org/project/seleniumwrapper/

Comment: я конечно не знаю, что такое seleniumwrapper, но я использую selenium webdriver.    refresher = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.b-scroll.js-search-left-content.js-preload-parent.b-preload-block.load")))  У ЕС есть несколько несколько десятков команд на видимость, присутствие, возможность клика и т. д. Возможно его можно как то использовать в ваше решение.    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Comment: @danilshik seleniumwrapper это просто обертка для selenium, она позволяет проще и быстрее работать. Можно было проверить видимость напрямую через selenium, но я посчитал, что это будет некрасиво.

Comment: Бедные питонисты. Едите кактус.